# Can't select element generated by third-party Vue plugin

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel, nuxt.js

I'm using [Owl Carousel for Vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel). It doesn't seem to work properly since all carousel items are visible in their global container, which is several screens wide (there's no `overflow: hidden` or any `max-width` to make only x items visible at a time).

Anyway I find myself forced to apply some `container` class to a wrapper that the plugin generates dynamically. To that end I do:

```
mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      document.querySelector('.owl-carousel').classList.add('container')
    })
}
```

But, `querySelector('.owl-carousel')` is `null` although I see it in the DOM.

How can I successfully select it?

Comment: Are you using `ssr/nuxt`? Could you show `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: Is `.owl-carousel` part of the shadow DOM?

Comment: Did you try to select element using $refs ? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow a jquery plugin wrapped into vue ... with like *200 lines* of props ...

props start [here](https://github.com/s950329/vue-owl-carousel/blob/436c30e0118c25915ff1a3dff9b0ae86ddde26bb/src/Carousel.vue#L23): L23

props end [here](https://github.com/s950329/vue-owl-carousel/blob/436c30e0118c25915ff1a3dff9b0ae86ddde26bb/src/Carousel.vue#L220) : L220

## but honestly just add your class [here](https://github.com/s950329/vue-owl-carousel/blob/436c30e0118c25915ff1a3dff9b0ae86ddde26bb/src/Carousel.vue#L6):

`<div :id="elementHandle" :class="['owl-carousel', 'owl-theme', 'your-class-here']">`

- [fork it](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)
- customize it
- [`npm install <git repo url>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Interesting workaround! Why a high number of props is a bad thing though? Do you think this package is poorly made and recommend against using it altogether?

Comment: @drake035 I think this should be a directive so you add it like `<div v-owlcarousel.{boleanOptions}="{...owlOptions}" >`, and it will stay reactive instead of a mounted one timer. Tons of props kinda feels very abstract. Btw you can also https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend this component - with your own template ;) - also mixin jquery into vue kinda feels like a overhead

Comment: @drake035 so yeah owlCarousel is dead - check github ;) it suggest to switch to tiny slider 2 here vue version: https://github.com/viktorlarsson/vue-tiny-slider based on vanilla - no jquery

Comment: Argh I wanted to grant you bounty but it just expired, really sorry!!